# Can we convert JSON Array of Objects to lightGalery Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, lightgallery

Hello all senior web developers, I am newbie for web development. I have used lightGallery plugin to view images. But my image path stored in array. In array element always dynamic that get from ajax response.  This is My array :

```
     var data = { "result" : [ 
                                { "file_name"  : "a.jpg" },
                                { "file_name"  : "b.png"},
                                  ......................
                             ]
     }
```

//   This is Lightgallery array syntax

```
     $(this).lightGallery({
       dynamic: true,
       dynamicEl: [{"src": 'your image path'}, 
                   {'src': 'your image path'},
                    ........................
                  ]
     })
```

//   I want like this :

```
     $(this).lightGallery({
       dynamic: true,
       dynamicEl: [{"src": 'a.jpg'}, 
                   {'src': 'b.jpg'},
                   ................
                  ]
     })
```

How to do that? Can or not?

thank for valuable help.

Comment: Have you tried to make objects from your ajax fetch and push into gallery array? Please add the code what you tried

Comment: Personally, if I control the data, I would make the response be the JSON you actually want, otherwise loop.

Comment: Yes, I have. but console show error wrong array format.

Comment: Here is my code : https://pastebin.com/ySeBVbjk

Comment: Is the file name corresponding to the full URL of your images?

Comment: only file name with extension

Comment: How can I concatenate url with image?

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is convenient for creating new `arrays` based on originals.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Input.
const input = {
  result: [ 
    { "file_name"  : "a.jpg" },
    { "file_name"  : "b.png"}
  ]
}

// To Dynamic.
const toDynamic = ({result}) => ({
  dynamic: true,
  dynamicEl: result.map(x => ({src: x.file_name}))
})

// Output.
const output = toDynamic(input)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original `var data` is actually an object - see how it starts with a `{`.

```js
const data = { "result" : [ 
  { "file_name"  : "a.jpg" },
  { "file_name"  : "b.png"},
]};
const dynamicElArr = data.result.map(({ file_name: src }) => ({ src }));
console.log(dynamicElArr);
```

Then you can use it for `dynamicEl`.