# The best way to change key and append value of Object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49441079/can-we-convert-json-array-of-objects-to-lightgalery-array-of-objects) I asked once, but I still didn't get my problem solved. I want to change key and append value of Object in javascript as below :

```
var dataObj = 
 [
  {
    "image": "a.jpg"
  },
  {
    "image": "b.png"
  },
  ..................
  ..................
];
```

I want to change like this:

```
dataObj = 
     [
      {
        "src": "stackoverfloow.com/uploads/a.jpg"
      },
      {
        "src": "stackoverfloow.com/uploads/b.png"
      },
      ..........................................
      ..........................................
    ];
```

Thank for help

Comment: use `map()` method

Answer (score 5):

Use `.map`:

```js
const data1 = [ 
  { "image"  : "a.jpg" },
  { "image"  : "b.png"},
];
const data2 = data1.map(({ image }) => ({ src: 'stackoverfloow.com/uploads/' + image }));
console.log(data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dataObj = [{ "image": "a.jpg" }, { "image": "b.png" }];

let resp = dataObj.map(x => ({"src": "stackoverfloow.com/uploads/" + x.image}));

console.log(resp);
```